# LastIndexOfAny not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this line in my C# code:

```
s_ind = formula.LastIndexOfAny(operators, 1);
```

Where operators is a char array with elements, +, -, *, /, and ^

formula is a string equal to "182+0"

The expression is returning -1, so it is saying there is no plus sign in the string "182+0"

What is going wrong?

Comment: In what way was the documentation unclear? I can pass your comments along to the documentation manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `1` is telling `LastIndexOfAny` to start at position 1 and search *backwards*.  Since your `+` is *after* position 1 it's not finding it.

If you want to find the very last occurence just use:

```
s_ind = formula.LastIndexOfAny(operators);
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kbkt4sh.aspx):

> The search starts at a specified character position and proceeds backward toward the beginning of the string